# problem of saving objects in parseSdk version 3.0.0 or more

Tags: flutter, dart, parse-server

I'm working today on flutter - parse server project and to make a push notification system I had to upgrade the versions of the majority of my packages, after finishing stabilize the project I found that the plugin of parse sdk after the upgrade has too many problems.

First I found that when I want to get mu current user from the server I got allows null,

My code:

```
  static Future<void> init() async {
    await UserService.getUpdatedUser();
  }

  static Future<User> getUpdatedUser() async {
    currentUser = await ParseUser.currentUser(customUserObject: User.clone());
    if (currentUser?.objectId != null) await currentUser.getUpdatedUser();
    return currentUser;
  }
```

( I called it after the initialization, and it works fine before on parse 1.0.27)

Second and the biggest problem that every time I what to right into the server (using `.save()`) I got that error:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception:
> Stack Overflow
> ParseObject._canbeSerialized package:parse_server_sdk/…/objects/parse_object.dart:222
> ParseObject._canbeSerialized package:parse_server_sdk/…/objects/parse_object.dart:234
> ParseObject._canbeSerialized package:parse_server_sdk/…/objects/parse_object.dart:245 ...
> ParseObject._canbeSerialized (p

Really I didn't know how to solve it whole the project now has many errors. (I can't return to 1.0.27 or 2.0.0 because I'm using dio ^4.0.0 and it didn't support it :( )

Update:

my user class:

```
class User extends ParseUser implements ParseCloneable {
  User(String username, String password, String emailAddress)
      : super(username, password, emailAddress);

  User.clone() : this(null, null, null);

  @override
  User clone(Map<String, dynamic> map) => User.clone()..fromJson(map);

  static const String nameKey = 'name';
  static const String surnameKey = 'surname';
  static const String phoneKey = 'phone';
  static const String cinKey = 'cin';
  static const String dobKey = 'dob';
  static const String positionKey = 'position';
  static const String useModeKey = 'useMode';
  static const String isLookingKey = 'isLooking';
  static const String driverKey = 'driver';
  static const String adminKey = 'admin';
  static const String creditCardKey = 'creditCard';
  static const String isSubscribedKey = 'isSubscribed';
  static const String finalSubscribeDateKey = 'finalSubscribeDate';
  static const String isDriverKey = 'isDriver';
  static const String countryCodeKey = 'countryCode';
  static const String partnerKey = 'partner';

  String get name => get<String>(nameKey);
  String get surname => get<String>(surnameKey);
  DateTime get dob => get<DateTime>(dobKey);
  String get phone => get<String>(phoneKey);
  String get cin => get<String>(cinKey);
  num get useMode => get<num>(useModeKey);
  bool get isLooking => get<bool>(isLookingKey);
  Driver get driver =>
      Driver().clone(get<ParseObject>(driverKey)?.toJson(full: true));
  String get creditCard => get<String>(creditCardKey);
  bool get isSubscribed => get<bool>(isSubscribedKey);
  DateTime get finalSubscribeDate => get<DateTime>(finalSubscribeDateKey);
  String get countryCode => get<String>(countryCodeKey);
  Partner get partner =>
      Partner().clone(get<ParseObject>(partnerKey)?.toJson(full: true));

  set name(String value) => set<String>(nameKey, value);
  set surname(String value) => set<String>(surnameKey, value);
  set dob(DateTime dob) =>
      set<dynamic>(dobKey, {"__type": "Date", "iso": "$dob"});
  set phone(String value) => set<String>(phoneKey, value);
  set cin(String value) => set<String>(cinKey, value);
  set useMode(num value) => set<num>(useModeKey, value);
  set isLooking(bool value) => set<bool>(isLookingKey, value);
  set driver(Driver value) => set<Driver>(driverKey, value);
  set creditCard(String value) => set<String>(creditCardKey, value);
  set isSubscribed(bool value) => set<bool>(isSubscribedKey, value);
  set finalSubscribeDate(DateTime finalSubscribeDate) => set<dynamic>(
      finalSubscribeDateKey, {"__type": "Date", "iso": "$finalSubscribeDate"});
  set isDriver(bool value) => set<bool>(isDriverKey, value);
  set countryCode(String value) => set<String>(countryCodeKey, value);
  set partner(dynamic value) => set<dynamic>(partnerKey, value);

  ParseGeoPoint get position => get<ParseGeoPoint>(positionKey);
  set position(ParseGeoPoint value) => set<ParseGeoPoint>(positionKey, value);

  String get fullname => '$name $surname';
  String get isVerifiedMsg =>
      emailVerified ?? false ? '' : '(' + 'isVerified'.tr + ')';

  bool get isDriver => driver?.objectId != null;

  static User fromParseUser(ParseUser parseUser) {
    if (parseUser?.objectId == null) return null;
    final user = User(
        parseUser.username, parseUser.password, parseUser.emailAddress)
      ..objectId = parseUser.objectId
      ..set(User.nameKey, parseUser.get(User.nameKey))
      ..set(User.surnameKey, parseUser.get(User.surnameKey))
      ..set(User.phoneKey, parseUser.get(User.phoneKey))
      ..set(User.cinKey, parseUser.get(User.cinKey))
      ..set(User.dobKey, parseUser.get(User.dobKey))
      ..set(User.positionKey, parseUser.get(User.positionKey))
      ..set(User.useModeKey, parseUser.get(User.useModeKey))
      ..set(User.isLookingKey, parseUser.get(User.isLookingKey))
      ..set(User.isSubscribedKey, parseUser.get(User.isSubscribedKey))
      ..set(
          User.finalSubscribeDateKey, parseUser.get(User.finalSubscribeDateKey))
      ..set(User.driverKey, Driver.parse(parseUser.get(User.driverKey)))
      ..set(User.countryCodeKey, parseUser.get(User.countryCodeKey));
    /* ..set(User.partnerKey,
                Partner.parse(parseUser.get(User.partnerKey))));*/

    /* if(user?.driver != null) {
      final driver = Driver.parse(user.get(User.driverKey));
      user.set(User.driverKey, driver);
    } */

    return user;
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks you have a custom class for User, right? Would you mind to share it?

Comment: ok I have updated my qst

Comment: Looking at the error that you share, it looks you are having an infinite loop somewhere in your code when trying to encode/decode the object. I'd try to include some breakpoints around the code and see which line is running recurrently.